# How to make a single video out of few pics of different resolution and videos of different resolution

Tags: video

We had a get-together party. I'm the most technically sound person in my group. I collected pictures & videos from all the friends who attended that party. Because, not all are taken using same camera. These pictures & videos are of different resolutions.

Now, I want to group all of them in to a single video and add some music etc. How can I achieve it? Which software would be better suited for my purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Any basic editing program will do the job for you. Are you on PC or Mac? If you have a PC then Windows Movie Maker is a very good, simple option.

To get the footage to the same codec and resolution you should use this free program called [mpeg streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/). I can't recommend a compression setting because I don't know the specs of the footage and what you are aiming to do with the video once it's been made. But there are many tutorials online that you can find with a quick google search.